# How to solve the following integral? 4

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I solve $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(  ax\right)  }{x^{2}+b^{2}}dx$?
I found the solution on Gradshteyn Table of Integral (3.723) which is $\frac{\pi e^{ab}}{2b}$ but I would like to know the step-by-step solution. Couldn't find the first reference.
Thanks

Comment: Let $f(z)=\mathrm{e}^{iaz}$ and use a semicircular contour in the upper half of the complex plane.

Comment: Almost the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140580/computing-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-xx2-a2dx-using-residue, you will need a couple of minor adjustments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $a,b>0$ we have
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+b^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\,\text{Re}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{iax}}{x^2+b^2}\,dx \tag{1}$$
and since
$$ \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iax}}{x^2+b^2},x=ib\right)=-\frac{i}{2b} e^{-ab}\tag{2} $$
by [the residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and the [ML lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) it follows that
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+b^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\,\text{Re}\left(\frac{2\pi}{2b}e^{-ab}\right) = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2b\, e^{ab}}}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: @Pierre: you're welcome.