# Is it possible to compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty {x \sin x\over x^4+1}dx$ without using complex analysis?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {x\sin x\over x^4+1}dx$$

By using things like Feynman's trick (Differentiating under the integral sign) or other high school level calculus concepts? I do not know things like residue theorem.

Comment: You can use or prove the Fourier inversion theorem.

Comment: I don't see a "high school level" way to do even $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} sin(x)/x dx$. You can check the methods how to solve that, to see how Fourier inversion would work on a simpler example.

Comment: @R_Berger I would have considered a function $f(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x }{x} \text{d}x$, from that 2f(0) = I and evaluate f'(t).. Something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1zhYD4x6mY

Comment: Maybe nice to know if you would also like to see it answered using other real methods.

Answer (score 8):

We have 
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{x\sin x}{x^4+1}\,dx= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sin(x)\left[\frac{1}{x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1}\right]\,dx $$
by partial fraction decomposition. On the other hand
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin x}{x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1}\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin\left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}}\,dx $$
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin x}{x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1}\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin\left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}}\,dx $$
so the whole problem boils down to evaluating
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}}\,dx=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}}\color{red}{=}{\pi \sqrt{2}\, e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}.$$
The last identity can be proved through the Laplace transform, the Fourier transform, Feynman's trick, ordinary differential equations, the residue theorem or the known relation between the Cauchy distribution and the Laplace distribution. A slick way is to notice that by integration by parts 
$$ \frac{1}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \cos(xz) \sqrt{2} e^{-\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}}\,dz = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(xz)}{x}\,e^{-\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}}\,dz $$
holds, then to apply Fubini's theorem to a double integral, recalling that for any $z\geq 0$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(xz)\cos(x)}{x}\,dx = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}0&\text{if}& z<1\\\frac{\pi}{4}&\text{if}&z=1\\\frac{\pi}{2}&\text{if}&z>1.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Yooo I was just writing this in full details!! Nicely done!

Comment: I also replicated the same computation, not knowing this approach is already done. Nice job! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

The same answer as @JackD'Aurizio with slightly more details. I was doing this after he sent his answer so I finish anyway.

Let $\alpha=\frac{1}{2\sqrt[]{2}}$. After partial fraction decomposition we get:
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^4+1}\,dx=-\alpha\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+\sqrt[]{2}x+1}\,dx+\alpha\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2-\sqrt[]{2}x+1}\,dx
\end{align}
Now define:
\begin{align}
I:=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+\sqrt[]{2}x+1}\,dx,\ \ \ \ J:=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2-\sqrt[]{2}x+1}\,dx
\end{align}
First we do $I$. Completing the squares in the denominator yields:
\begin{align}
I=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{(x+\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2})^2+\frac{1}{2}}\,dx
\end{align}
Substitute $u=x+\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2}$ and use the formula for $\sin(x+y)$:
\begin{align}
I&=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin\left(u-\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2}\right)}{u^2+\frac{1}{2}}\,du\\& = \int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(-\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2}\right)}{u^2+1}\,du+\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\cos(u)\sin\left(-\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2}\right)}{u^2+\frac{1}{2}}\,du\\
 \end{align}
The integral with $\sin(u)$ is convergent and the ingerand is an odd function, so it vanishes. Now we get:
\begin{align}
I=\sin\left(-\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2}\right)\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\cos(u)}{u^2+\frac{1}{2}}\,du
\end{align}
This integral can be done with the explicitly mentioned trick by you, namely Feynman's trick. It is done nicely with full details by user Mark Viola in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2480371). 
So we get:
\begin{align}
I=\sin\left(-\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2}\right) \frac{\pi\sqrt[]{2}}{e^{1/\sqrt[]{2}}}=-\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2}\right) \frac{\pi\sqrt[]{2}}{e^{1/\sqrt[]{2}}}
\end{align}
The same can be done for $J$ (do it yourself!). We get:
\begin{align}
J=\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2}\right)\frac{\pi\sqrt[]{2}}{e^{1/\sqrt[]{2}}}
\end{align}
Finally we get:

> \begin{align}
> \int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^4+1}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{e^{1/\sqrt[]{2}}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt[]{2}}{2}\right)
> \end{align}

Answer (score 3):

*Just using basic integration methods.*

Let us call $a,b,c,d$ the roots of $x^4+1=0$. Then using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac x{x^4+1}=\frac{a}{(a-b) (a-c) (a-d) (x-a)}+\frac{b}{(b-a) (b-c) (b-d) (x-b)}+\frac{c}{(c-a)
   (c-b) (c-d) (x-c)}+\frac{d}{(d-a) (d-b) (d-c) (x-d)}$$ which makes that we are left with four integrals looking like
$$I_r=\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x-r}\,dx=\int \frac{\sin(y+r)}{y}\,dy=\cos(r)\int \frac{\sin(y)}{y}\,dy+\sin(r)\int \frac{\cos(y)}{y}\,dy$$ that is to say
$$I_r=\cos (r)\, \text{Si}(y)+ \sin (r)\,\text{Ci}(y)$$ where appear sine and cosine integrals.

For sure, now the problem is to recombine all of that (tedious work) and replace $a,b,c,d$ by the roots of unity and finally integrate between the bounds. I let you the pleasure of doing it.

By the end, you should arrive to
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {x\sin x\over x^4+1}\,dx=\pi \,e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \,  \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Comment: The sine integral is a special function (cannot be evaluated). What we want is evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x-r}dx$ for $r \not \in \mathbb{R}$. How would you do it, and why don't you mention it

Comment: Knowing the value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(y)}{y}\,dy$ and $PV.\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(y)}{y}\,dy$ doesn't help for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x+i}dx$.

Comment: @reuns. I started my answer with *Just using basic integration methods*. For sure this involves sine and cosine integrals the values of which being known at infinity.  This method has been widely used for years in my research group. Nevertheless, I delete my answer and let you posting an answer using one of the many other possibilities.

Comment: Dear @ClaudeLeibovici, I undeleted your answer since it seems to be useful. Perhaps you can add some detail if necessary. :)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff. Thank you for doing it.

Comment: The main problem is that for $r \in \mathbb{C}$, $\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x-r}\,dx=\int \frac{\sin(y+r)}{y}\,dy=\cos(r)\int \frac{\sin(y)}{y}\,dy+\sin(r)\int \frac{\cos(y)}{y}\,dy$ is not true in real analysis, and in complex analysis it is not quite true neither because of the integration constants

Comment: @Claude Leibovici $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(y)}{y}\,dy=0$ not $-i\pi$.