# How does one evaluate $I(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{x(x^2-\alpha^2)}{x^2-\beta^2}\right)\frac{1}{x^2+\gamma^2} \, dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

I have been trying to evaluate this integral for a while now,
$$I(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{x(x^2-\alpha^2)}{x^2-\beta^2}\right)\frac{1}{x^2+\gamma^2} \, dx.$$
I first came across this integral on Quora (https://www.quora.com/What-improper-integrals-are-hard-to-solve).

Someone stated that this integral was submitted as a problem to the *Gazette of the Royal Mathematics Society of Spain* and was (at the time) still open, so the complete solution would not be published there. (have not been able to find the publication).

Although no derivation, a closed form expression was given:
$$I(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\frac{\pi}{2\gamma}e^{-\frac{\gamma(\alpha^2+\gamma^2)}{\beta^2+\gamma^2}}.$$
One might be wondering, why not just respond to the post on Quora? That I did. However, the thread seems to inactive.

I have tried several methods including the one employed by Mark Viola in this post ([Computing $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^{2} + a^{2}}dx$ using residue calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140580/computing-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-xx2-a2dx-using-residue)). Trying to work backwards from the closed form expression, by treating the term $ \frac{\gamma(\alpha^2+\gamma^2)}{\beta^2+\gamma^2}$ in exponent as one variable. However, I have not been able to succeed.

Hopefully, you can help me solve this integral/ give suggestions/ different methods.

edit: I found that when $\alpha=\beta$, the integral becomes
$I= \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x)\frac{1}{x^2+\gamma^2}dx$ , which evaluates to $I=\frac{\pi}{2\gamma}e^{-\gamma}$. This is comparable to the desired result. The argument in the exponent is different however.

Comment: I can’t really work on this problem as of right now but have you tried Feynman’s Trick or rewriting $\cos x$ as the real part of $e^{ix}$?

Comment: Have tried write the cosine in terms of exponentials followed by separating the integral and substitution of variables. As for Fyenman's trick, have attempted it, but tbh I wouldn't know with respect to what variable.

Comment: What are the conditions on the parameters $\alpha, \beta$, and $\gamma$? Based on the solution it appears at least that $\gamma > 0$.

Comment: $\alpha, \beta$ are equal or greater than 0 and $\gamma$ is greater than 0

Comment: The originial problem can be found [here](http://gaceta.rsme.es/secciones.php). It was asked in the 66th edition of 'Problemas y Soluciones' as 'Problema 248'. The solution is given in the 73rd edition. Some subtleties regarding the application of the residue theorem are not discussed in great detail, however.

Comment: Your notation is rather odd, with $\text{“}dx\text{''}$ occuring twice. Could it me that you meant the following? $$ I(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)= \int_0^\infty \cos \left( \frac{x(x^2-\alpha^2)}{x^2-\beta^2}\right)\frac{dx}{x^2+\gamma^2} $$

Comment: yah, that was a typo (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\alpha, \beta \geq 0$ and $\gamma > 0$ let
$$ f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} (z) = \frac{\exp \left(\mathrm{i} z \frac{z^2 - \alpha^2}{z^2 - \beta^2}\right)}{z^2 + \gamma^2} \, , \, z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{\pm\beta, \pm \mathrm{i} \gamma\} \, . $$
By symmetry we have
$$ I (\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} (x) \, \mathrm{d} x \, .$$
Clearly, the integral exists for every combination of parameters and is bounded by $\frac{\pi}{2 \gamma}$ .

---

We can compute its value using the residue theorem. First note that we have
$$ \operatorname{Res} (f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}, \mathrm{i} \gamma) = \frac{1}{2  \mathrm{i} \gamma} \exp \left(- \gamma \frac{\alpha^2 + \gamma^2}{\beta^2 + \gamma^2}\right) $$
and (by Jordan's lemma)
$$ \lim_{R \to \infty} \int \limits_{\Gamma_R} f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} (z) \, \mathrm{d} z = 0 \, ,$$
where $\Gamma_R$ is a semi-circle of radius $R > 0$ in the upper half-plane. A naive application of the residue theorem therefore yields
$$ I (\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ 2 \pi \mathrm{i} \operatorname{Res} (f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}, \mathrm{i} \gamma) - \lim_{R \to \infty} \int \limits_{\Gamma_R} f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} (z) \, \mathrm{d} z \right]= \frac{\pi}{2 \gamma} \exp \left(- \gamma \frac{\alpha^2 + \gamma^2}{\beta^2 + \gamma^2}\right) \, .$$
While the result is indeed correct, this calculation is only valid for $\alpha = \beta$ . In this case we obtain (as already mentioned in the question) $I(\alpha,\alpha,\gamma) = \frac{\pi}{2 \gamma}\mathrm{e}^{- \gamma}$ .

If $\alpha \neq \beta$ , $f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}$ has essential singularities on the real axis, namely at $\pm \beta$ . Thus we need to deform our contour using small semi-circles $\gamma_\varepsilon (\pm \beta)$ of radius $\varepsilon > 0$ centred at these points and show that their contribution to the integral vanishes as $\varepsilon \to 0$ .

---

For simplicity, I will only discuss the case $\beta = 0$ in detail. We want to find
$$ \int \limits_{\gamma_\varepsilon (0)} f_{\alpha,0,\gamma} (z) \, \mathrm{d} z = \varepsilon \int \limits_0^\pi \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \left[\phi + \varepsilon \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi} - \alpha^2 \varepsilon^{-1} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \phi}\right]}}{\gamma^2+\varepsilon^2 \mathrm{e}^{2 \mathrm{i} \phi}} \, \mathrm{d} \phi = \frac{\varepsilon}{\gamma^2} \int \limits_0^\pi \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \left[\phi - \alpha^2 \varepsilon^{-1} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \phi}\right]} \left[1 + \mathcal{O} (\varepsilon) \right] \, \mathrm{d} \phi \, .$$
The leading-order term can actually be calculated analytically: for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ we have
$$ \int \limits_0^\pi \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \left[\phi - z \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \phi}\right]} \, \mathrm{d} \phi = \mathrm{i} \left[(2 \operatorname{Si}(z) - \pi) z + 2 \cos(z)\right] \, . $$
The sine integral $\operatorname{Si}$ satisfies $\lim_{x \to \infty} \operatorname{Si}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so we obtain
$$ \int \limits_{\gamma_\varepsilon (0)} f_{\alpha,0,\gamma} (z) \, \mathrm{d} z \sim \frac{\mathrm{i} \varepsilon}{\gamma^2} \left[(2 \operatorname{Si}(\alpha^2 \varepsilon^{-1}) - \pi) \alpha^2 \varepsilon^{-1} + 2 \cos(\alpha^2 \varepsilon^{-1})\right] \stackrel{\varepsilon \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0 $$
as desired. Now we are allowed to apply the residue theorem , which yields
\begin{align}
I(\alpha,0,\gamma) &= \frac{1}{2} \left[ 2 \pi \mathrm{i} \operatorname{Res} (f_{\alpha,0,\gamma}, \mathrm{i} \gamma) - \lim_{R \to \infty} \int \limits_{\Gamma_R} f_{\alpha,0,\gamma} (z) \, \mathrm{d} z - \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int \limits_{\gamma_\varepsilon (0)} f_{\alpha,0,\gamma} (z) \, \mathrm{d} z \right] \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2 \gamma} \exp \left(- \frac{\alpha^2 + \gamma^2}{\gamma}\right) \, .
\end{align}

---

Almost the same calculation yields 
\begin{align}
I(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) &= \frac{1}{2} \left[ 2 \pi \mathrm{i} \operatorname{Res} (f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}, \mathrm{i} \gamma) - \lim_{R \to \infty} \int \limits_{\Gamma_R} f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} (z) \, \mathrm{d} z - \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int \limits_{\gamma_\varepsilon (\beta)} f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} (z) \, \mathrm{d} z - \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int \limits_{\gamma_\varepsilon (-\beta)} f_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} (z) \, \mathrm{d} z \right] \\ 
&= \frac{\pi}{2 \gamma} \exp \left(- \gamma \frac{\alpha^2 + \gamma^2}{\beta^2 + \gamma^2}\right)
\end{align}
for $\beta > 0$ .

---

Combining these results we conclude that the integral is given by
$$ I(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \frac{\pi}{2 \gamma} \exp \left(- \gamma \frac{\alpha^2 + \gamma^2}{\beta^2 + \gamma^2}\right) $$
for every $\alpha,\beta \geq 0$ and $\gamma > 0$ .

Comment: It would seem that the OP seeks a real analysis only approach inasmuch as the cited reference uses contour integration.