# Contour integral of $\displaystyle\oint_{c} \frac{e^{ix}}{1+z^{2}} dz$

Tags: solution-verification, contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I want to find $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^{2} + a^{2}}\ dx$

using

$$\oint_{c} \frac{e^{ix}}{1+z^2} \cdot d z$$

over the upper half of a large semicircle enclosing $z=i$  (not **$\oint_{c} \frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^{2}} dz$**)

For very large semicircle,  the above integral   reduces to $$\oint \frac{e^{i x}}{1+z^{2}} d z=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i x}}{1+x^{2}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x d x}{1+x^{2}}+i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^{2}} d x$$

So we have $$\oint \frac{e^{i x}}{1+z^{2}} d z=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^{2}} d x+i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^{2}} d x$$

Also by residue theorem $$\oint \frac{e^{i x}}{1+z^{2}} d z=2 \pi i b_{1}$$  and then

> $$b_{1}=\lim _{z \rightarrow i} \frac{e^{i x}(z-i)}{1+z^{2}}=\frac{1}{2 i}$$ ( as $z$--> $i$ , the real part $x$--> $0$ )

Therefore we have$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^{2}} d x+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^{2}} d x=\frac{2 \pi i}{2 i}$$

And hence $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^{2}} d x=\pi$$  which is incorrect.

Why am I getting wrong result. I suspect the above highlighted portion.
Can anyone please help me. Thank you so much

Comment: For those who are interested in the integral: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140580/computing-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-xx2-a2dx-using-residue)

Comment: Thank you whoever opened this question. It was not a duplicate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you did not change consequently the real variable $x$ to complex variable $z$. As a consequence your integrated function is wrong as seemingly $x$ is independent of $z$.

As a result you have wrongly computed the residue at $z=i$. The correct value is:
$$
\operatorname{res}(f(z),i)=\lim _{z \rightarrow i} \frac{e^{i \color{red}z}(z-i)}{1+z^{2}}=\frac{e^{-1}}{2 i}.
$$

---

**UPDATE (after OP question was edited clarifying that symbol $x$ used in the integrated function is assumed to mean the real part of $z$)**

You cannot integrate the function $$f(z)=\frac{e^{i\operatorname{Re}z}}{1+z^2}$$
with the help of the residue theorem because the function is holomorphic at **no** point of the complex plane, whereas the residue theorem [requires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) it to be holomorphic at **any** point of the part of the complex plane surrounded by the contour except for a finite set of isolated points.

To avoid this you shall instead use the meromorphic function
$$
f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2}
$$
as suggested above.

Comment: As $z$--> $i$ , the real part $x$--> 0

Comment: If you intend to claim that $x$ in your formulas means the real part of $z$, then you should always avoid this and express the integrated function via the variable of integration (in your case it is $z$).

Comment: Pardon me but I'm not able to understand. Could you please explain it?

Comment: If your integrated function contains a symbol $x$ it means a parameter independent of $z$. If your intend to claim that it is a function of $z$ you should explicitly  do this (e.g. replace $x$ with $\operatorname{Re} z$) or at least indicate this meaning of '$x$'.

Comment: thanks ,but the problem wont go away even then.

Comment: See the edit of my answer.

Comment: Yes that's it. Basically $e^_{ix}$ isn't analytic